# How to prevent app from going to sleep (using monaca.io)

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, monaca

in the past I used the *cordova-plugin-powermanagement* plugin to prevent the device screen from sleep.

But it seems that this plugin no longer works with Cordova 12 and target level 33

Does anyone who develops Android apps using monaca.io have any suggestions on how to prevent the screen from blanking?